# Nested forms with three models through another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

I have trying to create a nested form with three models associated with through in one.

This is the schema:

[image]

These are the models:

../app/models/alimento.rb:

```
class Alimento < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :calorias, :nome, :refeicaos_attributes

  validates :nome, :calorias, :presence => { :message => "nao pode ficar em branco" }
    has_many :controles, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :refeicaos, through: :controles
    has_many :diarios, through: :controles

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :controles
end
```

../app/models/refeicao.rb:

```
class Refeicao < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :nome, :alimentos_attributes, :controles_attributes, :diario_attributes

    validates :nome, :presence => { :message => "nao pode ficar em branco" }

    has_many :controles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :alimentos, through: :controles
    has_many :diarios, through: :controles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :controles
end
```

../app/models/diario.rb:

```
class Diario < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :controles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :refeicaos, through: :controles
    has_many :alimentos, through: :controles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :controles

  attr_accessible :data, :controles_attributes, :refeicaos_attributes, :alimentos_attributes
end
```

../app/models/controle.rb:

```
class Controle < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :alimento 
  belongs_to :refeicao
  belongs_to :diario

  attr_accessible :quantidade, :alimento_id, :refeicao_id, :diario_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :alimento
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :refeicao
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :diario

end
```

I created many `alimentos` (food) and `refeições` (meals), now I need create a
daily control of diet through the model Diario that can contain many `alimentos` and `refeições` through the Controle (control) model.

../app/controllers/diarios_controller.rb:

```
class DiariosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /diarios
  # GET /diarios.json
  def index
    @diarios = Diario.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @diarios }
    end
  end

  # GET /diarios/1
  # GET /diarios/1.json
  def show
    @diario = Diario.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @diario }
    end
  end

  # GET /diarios/new
  # GET /diarios/new.json
  def new
    @diario = Diario.new
  end

  # GET /diarios/1/edit
  def edit
    @diario = Diario.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /diarios
  # POST /diarios.json
  def create
    @diario = Diario.new(params[:diario])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @diario.save
        format.html { redirect_to @diario, notice: 'Diario was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @diario, status: :created, location: @diario }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @diario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /diarios/1
  # PUT /diarios/1.json
  def update
    @diario = Diario.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @diario.update_attributes(params[:diario])
        format.html { redirect_to @diario, notice: 'Diario was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @diario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /diarios/1
  # DELETE /diarios/1.json
  def destroy
    @diario = Diario.find(params[:id])
    @diario.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to diarios_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to do the "[Nested Model Form (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)" example.

Views:

../app/views/diarios/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @diario do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :data %>
    <%= f.date_select :data %>
    <br>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :refeicaos do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'refeicao_fields', f: builder %>      
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Adicionar Refeição", f, :refeicaos %>
</br>
</br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Cadastrar Controle" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</br>
<%= link_to 'Voltar', root_path %>
```

../app/views/diarios/_refeicao_fields.html.erb:

```
<fieldset>
  <strong>Refeição: </strong></br>
  <%= f.label :nome, "Nome da Refeição", :style => 'margin-left: 5px;' %>
  <%= collection_select(:refeicao, :id, Refeicao.order(:nome), :id, :nome) %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remover Refeição" %>
</br>
</br>
  <strong>Alimentos:</strong></br>
  <%= f.fields_for :alimentos do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'alimento_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Adicionar Refeição", f, :alimentos %>
</fieldset>
```

../app/views/diarios/_alimento_fields.html.erb:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :alimento, "Nome do Alimento:" %>
  <%= collection_select(:alimento, :id, Alimento.order(:nome), :id, :nome) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= f.fields_for :controles do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'controle_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "Remover alimento", '#', class: "remove_fields" %></br>

</fieldset>
```

../app/views/diarios/_controle_fields.html.erb:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :alimento, "Quantidade:", :style => 'margin-left: 42px;' %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantidade, :style => 'width: 50px;' %>
</fieldset>
```

Custom helper created:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Diarios#new

Showing D:/aplicacoes_indie/AppDieta/app/views/diarios/_refeicao_fields.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `alimentos' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #13):

10:   <%= f.fields_for :alimentos do |builder| %>
11:     <%= render 'alimento_fields', f: builder %>
12:   <% end %>
13:   <%= link_to_add_fields "Adicionar Refeição", f, :alimentos %>
14: </fieldset>
```

I've trying a lot of ways, but I can't solve this. The idea is: A Diario > with 1 or more refeicoes > with 1 or more `alimentos` and save each association through controle model.

Where am I wrong?

**EDITED***

thanks for the answer, now the form appears

But should appear the number field 'quantidade' from controle below the select from alimento like this:

http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/123/917/full/model2.jpg?1385480010

**../app/view/diarios/_alimento_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :alimento, "Nome do Alimento:" %>
  <%= collection_select(:alimento, :id, Alimento.order(:nome), :id, :nome) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= f.fields_for :controles do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'controle_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "Remover alimento", '#', class: "remove_fields" %></br>

</fieldset>
```

**../app/view/diarios/_controle_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :controle, "Quantidade:", :style => 'margin-left: 42px;' %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantidade, :style => 'width: 50px;' %>
</fieldset>
```

One more thing, how can i mount the create action of Diario to get all the values of selects of alimentos and refeicaos and save each in controle model? Because I save and only create a Diario object with none association.

**../app/controllers/diarios_controller.rb action create**

```
  def create
    @diario = Diario.new(params[:diario])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @diario.save
        format.html { redirect_to @diario, notice: 'Diario was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @diario, status: :created, location: @diario }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @diario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I believe you are getting this error because `Diario` can only accept nested attributes for `:controles` and not `:refeicaos` or `:alimentos`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these are the only `accepts_nested_attributes_for` statements that you should need:

```
class Diario < ActiveRecord::Base
accepts_nested_attributes_for :refeicaos
```

And:

```
class Refeicao < ActiveRecord::Base
accepts_nested_attributes_for :alimentos
```

Right now the `<%= f.fields_for :refeicaos do |builder| %>` statement is setting up the `builder` but `builder.object` is nil.

**Edit** - Changed field names to plural forms since this was a has_many relationship.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now the form appears

But should appear the number field 'quantidade' from controle below the select from alimento, i edited the question with a image.

Comment: I missed that you had a field coming from `Controle`.  You will want to keep the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :controles` statement in the `Alimento` model.

Comment: Yes the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :controles` already there in `Alimento` but doesn't appear the field quantidade.

Comment: This form layout should work if the `diario` was already saved and the appropriate `controles` table row exists to connect all three records.  But I'm not sure if there is a way to make this work when building the initial `diario` inside of the `new` action.  It seems like Rails will always try to save two rows into the `controles` table in that case--one for the `diario`-`refeicao` link and one for the `refeicao`-`alimento` link.  You might need to split this up into different views rather than editing it all at once.

Comment: But a i can't save the diario and after that save the controles in the same action?

Comment: As far as I know, the nested forms format assumes that you're nesting models that have simple join tables that just link two tables together.  Upon creation it will make a new row in the join table for each `fields_for` connection.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
class Alimento < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :calorias, :nome, :refeicaos_attributes

  validates :nome, :calorias, :presence => { :message => "nao pode ficar em branco" }
    has_many :controles, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :refeicaos, through: :controles
    has_many :diarios, through: :controles

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :controles
end

class Refeicao < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :nome, :alimentos_attributes, :controles_attributes, :diario_attributes

    validates :nome, :presence => { :message => "nao pode ficar em branco" }

    has_many :controles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :alimentos, through: :controles
    has_many :diarios, through: :controles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :alimentos
end

class Diario < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :controles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :refeicaos, through: :controles
    has_many :alimentos, through: :controles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :refaicoas

  attr_accessible :data, :controles_attributes, :refeicaos_attributes, :alimentos_attributes
end

class Controle < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :alimento 
  belongs_to :refeicao
  belongs_to :diario

  attr_accessible :quantidade, :alimento_id, :refeicao_id, :diario_id

end
```

Comment: I Tried to do this and get this error:

`NoMethodError in Diarios#new`

`Showing D:/aplicacoes_indie/AppDieta/app/views/diarios/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:`

`undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):`

`1: <%= form_for @diario do |f| %>
2:   <div class="field">
3:     <%= f.label :data %>
4:     <%= f.date_select :data %>`

Comment: Did you change anything in your `new` action? If not, try `<%= form_for Diario.new do |f| %>` instead.

Comment: I Solved this just adding a 's' in name of accepts_nested_attributes_for, e.g: Class Refeicao accepts_nested_attributes_for :alimentos instead of accepts_nested_attributes_for :alimento